# Квадратный LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, android-sdk

У меня возникла потребность в `LinearLayout` квадратной формы. В интернете нашел такое решение.

```
public class SquareLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public SquareLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int size = width > height ? height : width;
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
    }
}
```

И использование в xml:

```
<com.dnt.dimantik.gamezfinalv.controllers.SquareLinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

</com.dnt.dimantik.gamezfinalv.controllers.SquareLinearLayout>
```

Квадрат получился, проверил это установив цвет фона. Но проблема заключается в том, что элементы, которые я помещаю в мой кастомный `SquareLayout` не отображаются.

К примеру:

```
<com.dnt.dimantik.gamezfinalv.controllers.SquareLinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:text="Hello"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Hello"/>

</com.dnt.dimantik.gamezfinalv.controllers.SquareLinearLayout>
```

Ни текст ни кнопка не показываются, один только квадрат. Что делать?

Comment: Он не лишний, он нужны для родительского контейнера, и нет, не совпадает цвет, а если бы даже совпадал, как тогда объяснить что не виден Button

Comment: вы забыли добавить super.onMeasure (widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec) в класс.

Comment: Да, все получилось! Спасибо)

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Вы забыли вызвать `super.onMeasure (widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec)`.

Приведите код метода к данному виду:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure (widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int size = width > height ? height : width;
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
    }
```